# Speeding up large number of requests to generate Dropbox shareable link with Python SDK?

Tags: python, python-2.7, client, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am generating shareable links for a huge number of files using the Dropbox Core API (Python 2.7). For every single file I run:

```
dropbox_file = dropbox_client.share(item_filename, short_url=False)
item_url = dropbox_file[u'url']
```

For 1k files for example this takes about 30 minutes. Bandwidth is not the issue - it's the time required for every single request. Is there a way to pass a list of files instead of individual file names - or similar - for speeding this process up?

Reference:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs/python#DropboxClient.share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to create these links in bulk, but you could make multiple requests in parallel. I'd suggest experimenting with parallel calls to find the right rate.

Also consider if there's a different way to accomplish your goal (like sharing an entire folder at once).

Comment: I maintain a small mediawiki bot, which adds links to individual files in a Dropbox to a private wiki. Lot's of pdf and word files basically. Their names and locations change often, so the wiki needs frequent updates as well. Parallel requests seem like a good idea. Could you provide a rough example of how this could look like? Multi-threading of some sort?